# Google rich snippet - Missing required field "entry-title"

Tags: microdata, microformats, google-rich-snippets

I was trying to see if the microdata was configured well on my website, using the [google structured data testing tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?q=www.primapaginaonline.it%2F2014%2F07%2F06%2Fpietraia-dei-poeti-tagliodiverso%2F) and it gives some errors. In this question, I'm asking about the first: `Missing required field "entry-title".`

[image]
I already enclosed the title of the post in `entry-title` class but it is not working. It is the code of my page that regards the error:

```
 <header itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    <figure>
       <img width="674" height="250" src="http://www.primapaginaonline.it/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/tagliodiverso-674x250.jpeg?3ef148" class="attachment-topimage wp-post-image" alt="tagliodiverso" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" /></figure>
    </figure>
<div itemprop="articleSection" class="single-page-category">Cultura</div>
<h1 itemprop="headline" class="entry-title single-entry-title"> Tagliodiverso, gli appuntamenti della Pietraia dei Poeti</h1>   
<div itemprop="description" class="meta-description">Con Tagliodiverso il museo a cielo aperto Pietraia dei Poeti stila un cartellone di incontri culturali incentrati sulla disabilità e l'accessibilità.</div>
    <div class="single-post-meta"></div>
</header>
```

Comment: Note that your code doesn’t include Microdata. I guess you use **Microformats**, but your code snippet doesn’t show which Microformat (the top-level class is missing).

Comment: Well, I don't know but it hadn't pasted the class in the header tag, I edited now

Comment: But there aren’t any Microdata properties (`itemprop`) now? You only create an `Article` item but don’t give any properties (like title, URL, image etc.) for this article.

Comment: Ok, it wasn't pasting the itemprop element, now there is all, thanks

Comment: Alright. But I don’t get any error in Google’s testing tool for this code.

Comment: Added the screenshot with the error in the first post

Comment: I guess you are testing the full page (via URL), but testing your code included in the question doesn’t yield any errors/warnings.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing the entire page and gives that error. Looking at the tutorials online, it seems that can be resolved giving the entry-title class to the title of the article, but in my case it's not working. That's why I posted the code of that part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I must enclose all the article in a `<div class="hentry">` tag and all works!